CSV file not found error in html file in pyscript tag . Running this html file in python Django web framework
I am learning python django web framework . Reading csv file content and showing in pandas dataframe but getting error file not found. Tried all possible options using latest , alpha pyscript release .
Tried absolute path as well as relative path . When running index.html it gives csv file not found error .
CSV file is alreday there in the directory where index.html is located .
       <py-env>

          -numpy
          - pandas
          - paths:
            - ./customer.csv
        </py-env>
         
<py-script>
         import pandas as pd
         import numpy as np
         df = pd.read_csv("./customer.csv")
         print(df.head())
  </py-script>
  


CSV file is alreday there in the directory where index.html is located The python code is looking for the file in the current directory, which is not necessarily the same directory as index.html.  You can use this code to see the actual current directory import os; print(os.getcwd())

you should put it in your app folder (the one with views.py) not the templates one

"Tried all possible options". Besides the one you show in the code block, which doesn't match any current example I am familiar with, what did you actually try? What more recent SO answers did you look at about it that didn't work? The second thing emphasized with a heading in How do I ask a good question? is "Search, and research". You are using outdated approaches. <py-env> hasn't been a thing for while now, see here & ...

 & here. (If characters weren't at a premium in comments, in the last comment I would have said "hasn't been a thing for a long while now".) With something like pyscript that is developing fast, it is important to keep up with the latest documentation and examples, as to use them as guides. The tiny snippet you  have provided here doesn't reflect doing that. (Please also note in the guide 'How do I ask a guide question?', it emphasizes to help others to reproduce the problem and actually include minimal workable code.) The ...

 current pysscript examples are available here. I have several examples here that work to read data into Pandas. The blurb were I link to describes some resources and approaches you can use and the HTML files themselves have additional links in them to help you.

You can read csv file in the following way https://_12.pyscriptapps.com/bold-credit/latest/     The packages and files can even be mentioned in the separate .toml file.
